# how to get document comparing two felids of same document (nested fields) mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5a3218bbdcb7c38fd3731232"),   
"json" : {
    "query_by_gtin_response:queryByGtinResponse" : {
        "xmlns" : "urn:gs1:tsd:query_by_gtin_response:xsd:1", 
        "productData" : {
            "productDataRecord" : [
                {
                    "module" : [
                        {
                            "product_tracking_information_module" : {                                    
                                "createdDate" : "2017-12-13T13:30:08.297Z",                                    
                                "updatedDate" : "2017-12-13T13:30:08.297Z",                                      
                            }
                        }, 
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

get above document if createdDate = updatedDate.I have used $where but i think because of nesting it is not working.Can you please suggest how to get this document .I am building query using java.

Comment: So check all modules for each product data record return the document when there is a match for any module for any product data. Is that what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the **$where** filter use the **this** or **obj** keyword to access the current document properties and compare those values:

```
this.json.query_by_gtin_response:queryByGtinResponse.productData.productDataRecord.module.product_tracking_information_module.createDate == this.json.query_by_gtin_response:queryByGtinResponse.productData.productDataRecord.module.product_tracking_information_module.updateDate
```

**EDIT**

The **$where** filter expects a javascript expression or a function that returns a boolean. With this and since you are using arrays, functions [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some) and [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/every) can be used on those arrays.

Let's suppose that we have a collection **T** like this:

```
a: {b : [{c: Date, d: Date}]}
```

If we want documents that at least have one match element we use **some** like this:

```
db.T.find({$where: "this.a.b.some((el) => el.c.valueOf() == el.d.valueOf())"})
```

If all elements of the array have to match the condition, we use **every**:

```
db.T.find({$where: "this.a.b.every((el) => el.c.valueOf() == el.d.valueOf())"})
```

Now, you collection has a nested array. With these, 4 posibilitys are present:

1: Select all documents that at least have one createdDate == updatedDate, no matter in wich "productDateRecord" element it is.

```
db.T.find({$where: "this.json.query_by_gtin_response:queryByGtinResponse.productData.productDataRecord.some((outside) => outside.module.some((inside) inside.createdDate.valueOf() == inside.updatedDate.valueOf()))"})
```

2: Select all documents where all "productDateRecord" object have at least one createdUpdate == updatedDate, no matter in wich "module" it is.

```
db.T.find({$where: "this.json.query_by_gtin_response:queryByGtinResponse.productData.productDataRecord.every((outside) => outside.module.some((inside) => inside.createdDate.valueOf() == inside.updatedDate.valueOf()))"})
```

3: Select all documents that at least have one "productDateRecord" where all "module" elements have createdUpdate == updatedDate

```
db.T.find({$where: "this.json.query_by_gtin_response:queryByGtinResponse.productData.productDataRecord.some((outside) => outside.module.every((inside) => inside.createdDate.valueOf() == inside.updatedDate.valueOf()))"})
```

4: Select all documents where every "productDateRecord" have all "module" elements with createdUpdate == updatedDate

```
db.T.find({$where: "this.json.query_by_gtin_response:queryByGtinResponse.productData.productDataRecord.every((outside) => outside.module.every((inside) => inside.createdDate.valueOf() == inside.updatedDate.valueOf()))"})
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help.I have tried the same but `productDataRecord` and `module` is array so i need something like `this.json.query_by_gtin_response:queryByGtinResponse.productData.productDataRecord[0].module[0].product_tracking_information_module.createDate == this.json.query_by_gtin_response:queryByGtinResponse.productData.productDataRecord[0].module[0].product_tracking_information_module.updateDate`
but the position in array is not alway fix(index may vary)..can you please help

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives me output `5a3218bbdcb7c38fd3731232` :

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
    DB database = mongoClient.getDB("test");
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("json.query_by_gtin_response:queryByGtinResponse.productData.productDataRecord.module.product_tracking_information_module.updatedDate", "2017-12-13T13:30:08.297Z");
    DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("testData");
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
    DBObject jo = cursor.one();
    System.out.println((String)cursor.one().get("_id"));
```

Note that on the db console I ran the following commands:

```
use test

t = {   "_id" : "5a3218bbdcb7c38fd3731232",      "json" : {       "query_by_gtin_response:queryByGtinResponse" : {           "xmlns" : "urn:gs1:tsd:query_by_gtin_response:xsd:1",            "productData" : {               "productDataRecord" : [                   {                       "module" : [                           {                               "product_tracking_information_module" : {                                                                       "createdDate" : "2017-12-13T13:30:08.297Z",                                                                       "updatedDate" : "2017-12-13T13:30:08.297Z"                                                                     }                           }                        ]                   }                 ]           }       }   } }


db.testData.insert( t );
```

I am using a maven project with following entry in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks,but i don't know the value of updatedDate prior so i need to compare this from same document.Can you please suggest